# FCM does not work well with Chrome (Ubuntu)

Tags: google-chrome, web-push

I need to implement the FCM on the web, every thing is OK but I didn't get the endpoint this is my code

```
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
   console.log('Service Worker is supported');
   navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js').then(function() {
     return navigator.serviceWorker.ready;
   }).then(function(reg) {

     console.log('Service Worker is ready :^)', reg);
     reg.pushManager.subscribe({userVisibleOnly: true}).then(function(sub) {
   // not reached here
       console.log('endpoint:', sub.endpoint);
     });
   }).catch(function(error) {
     console.log('Service Worker error :^(', error);
   });
  }
```

i got

Service Worker is supported

Service Worker is ready :^)

chrome version : Version 54.0.2840.71 (64-bit)

OS ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0):

Because the bug is in Chrome and on a particular machine / environment I think you are hitting this bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=623062#c37

Basically the GCM database used by Chrome is corrupted in such a way that Chrome isn't catching the problem and resolving it - resulting in this indeterminate time of nothing happening.

Comment: on windows 7 at the same version of chrome its works fine , windows 10 on the same version of chrome its not works , firefox on the ubuntu and the others os , works fine